# iOS TestFlight - Internal Testers not appearing on User list

Tags: email, testflight, internal, invite

I added internal testers & iTunes Connect said it sent the invite emails, but the emails were never received and the testers never appeared on the Users list. It seems like the testers just went into limbo. Does anyone know what i did wrong? & I haven't added any external testers.

Comment: @Pang Cool, tho we havn't clarified that iTunes Connect is down yet, that's just what we're "hoping" lol

Comment: Having the same problem in adding internal users and also invite a user to test a beta version as internal tester.

Comment: All the invite emails suddenly came in in bulk at around 17:30 so i guess the Apple server was down over the weekend

Comment: Today facing exact same issue ! Any solution ?

Comment: ... And finally after 3 days, able to receive confirmation mail and hence i am able to add internal testers. Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are adding correct AppleID which your users are used to install application from iTunes.